# Debian Buster slow only on one terminal

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, gnome

Please: my main terminal is a HP Compaq LA1905wg and my other terminal is (an old) HP 1702.

Applications are running normally on the main terminal, but if I drag any of them to the 1702 my whole system starts to crawl.   gnome-shell consumes over 100% of cpu and when I hit a key it is repeated dramatically.  "l" becomes "lllllll".

I am using Gnome as delivered, nothing tweaked.

Comment: What GPU are you using on your computer? Are both monitors connected to the same one? (If you call them terminals, they're at best _very_ dumb terminals, as they rely on the computer's GPU to provide the video output and don't really have any terminal-like capabilities of their own.)

Comment: Its possible the 1702 is connected to the computers integrated graphics port. Maybe swap the ports they are both connected to; if the 1702 becomes normal and the Compaq slows down, then that's probably the cause. I don't think its the 1702's own fault, since it's just a display.

Comment: QF: yes, you are correct.  If I swop over the physical connections the problem appears on the 1905.  The 1905 is connected to the vga port.  The 1702 is connected to the hdmi plug via a hdmi->vga convertor.  Perhaps if I buy a proper hdmi monitor ...... ?

Comment: @Saxtheowl: Please use the “Edit Summary” field to summarize (i.e., describe) your edit.  Tags are not considered to be formatting, so ‘‘improved formatting’’ is not an appropriate summary / description of an edit that consists solely of adding tag(s).